# select con condicion si es null agarrar otra columna en una FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server

Intento hacer una consulta en una FUNCTION pero esta vez con una condición que si en mi tabla el campo  "Strnttr" es null agarrar el valor de otra columna les muestro mi FUNCTION

es de la tabla OJDT donde lo quiero aplicar

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SBO_FN_LGS_OBT_OBTENER_Fecha_doc](@Code varchar(50))  
RETURNS varchar(250)   
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @resp datetime;  
    declare @st int;
    select @st=StornoToTr from OJDT
     SELECT @resp =b.TaxDate
    from OJDT A INNER JOIN 
     (
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO as tipo from oinv  union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from opch union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from ovpm union all    
    select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from ORCT union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from ODLN union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from orin union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from orct union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from owtr 
    ) b 
     ON A.TRANSID=B.TRANSID  and a.U_LGS_TIPO=b.tipo
        where a.transid= @code 
    RETURN format(@resp,'dd/MM/yyyy');  
END;
```

Comment: Lo acabo de editar

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Donde esta ese campo que especificas?

Comment: y te importa el nombre del campo o solo el valor?

Comment: si el valor de `Strnttr` es null, se procesara tu query?

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de la versión de tu motor puedes usar:

MSQL 2008 o inferior (O ANSI SQL):

```
SELECT @st = ISNULL(StornoToTr, OTRA_COLUMNA)
```

MSQL superior a 2008:

```
SELECT @st = COALESCE(StornoToTr, OTRA_COLUMNA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberias intentar poner una sentencia CASE

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COLUMNA1 IS NULL THEN COLUMNA2 ELSE COLUMNA3 END CAMPO
FROM [TABLA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifique tu query, con esta funcion [**(ISNULL)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms184325(v=sql.120).aspx) logras que tu variable **`@st`** tome el valor de la **`"otracolumna"`** en caso que **`StornoToTr`** sea **`null`**

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SBO_FN_LGS_OBT_OBTENER_Fecha_doc](@Code varchar(50))  
      RETURNS varchar(250)   
      AS   
      BEGIN  
          DECLARE @resp datetime;  
          declare @st int;
          select @st=ISNULL(StornoToTr,otracolumna) from OJDT
           SELECT @resp =b.TaxDate
          from OJDT A INNER JOIN 
           (
          select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO as tipo from oinv  union all
          select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from opch union all
          select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from ovpm union all    
          select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from ORCT union all
          select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from ODLN union all
          select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from orin union all
          select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from orct union all
          select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from owtr 
          ) b 
           ON A.TRANSID=B.TRANSID  and a.U_LGS_TIPO=b.tipo
              where a.transid= @code 
          RETURN format(@resp,'dd/MM/yyyy');  
      END;
```

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios llego a ponerlo asi Saludos
(editare)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SBO_FN_LGS_OBT_OBTENER_Fecha_doc](@codes int)
RETURNS varchar(250)   
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @resp datetime;  
    DECLARE @aa int;  

     SELECT @resp =b.TaxDate,
     @codes=(case when a.StornoToTr is null then a.TransId
                when a.StornoToTr <> null then a.StornoToTr
                else a.TransId end) 

    from OJDT A INNER JOIN 
     (
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO as tipo from oinv  union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from opch union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from ovpm union all    
    select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from ORCT union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from ODLN union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from orin union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TPCE,TaxDate,U_LGS_TPCE from orct union all
    select transid,U_LGS_TIPO,TaxDate,U_LGS_TIPO from owtr

    ) b 
     ON A.TRANSID=B.TRANSID  and a.U_LGS_TIPO=b.tipo
        where a.transid= @codes
    RETURN format(@resp,'dd/MM/yyyy');  
END;
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta? podrias explicar que es?

Comment: SI ,asi lo puse ya me funciona :)

Comment: Ninguna de las respuestas soluciono tu problema?